# Obj-C, Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I'm getting an analyzer warning, since upgrading...

`Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'`

Dunno whats wrong with it ?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self == [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self initLayers];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get rid of the second equals sign. The proper `if` statement is:

```
if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
```

The point of this is that the super implementation could return a different, but still valid, object than the current value of self. In this case, your if statement will be false, since the objects are different, and so your initialization won't occur. However, since it returned a different object, the super implementation should have released the old self, which is what you are returning. This means you are probably returning an invalid pointer.

By using only one equals sign, you set the variable instead of comparing it. Since `if(object)` is true if `object` is not `nil`, it is equivalent to this:

```
if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) != nil)
```

Or, the easier to understand version:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if(self != nil)
```

This code reassigns `self` to be the value returned by the super initializer, instead of just assuming the value returned is the same. This is the same reason why it is important to set a variable to the result of the `init...` method and not `alloc`.

```
// good
id object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
// bad
id object = [MyClass alloc];
[object init];
```

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly the syntax is `self = ...` not `self == ...`. The syntax uses the returned value from assignment.

Answer (score 2):

your returning self not initialized

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initLayers];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You must assign the result of [super init] to self. In your snippet you are using "==" which is only a comparison, not the assignment operator.